# Using Dependency Injection in ASP.NET MVC3 Model Binder

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject

I'm working on MVC3 website, trying to use Ninject to resolve my dependencies. I have the following scenario:

```
public class UserModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    //[Inject]
    public UserDataService userData { get; set; }

    public object BindModel(
        ControllerContext controllerContext,
        ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        Guid UserID =
            (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;

        //userDataService = DependencyResolver.Current
        //    .GetService<UserDataService>();

        User user = userDataService.GetUser(UserID);

        return user;
    }
}
```

*noticed the commented lines of code?*

I do register the binder in `Global.asax` as

```
ModelBinders.Binders[typeof(User)] = new UserModelBinder();
```

So I can't really do injection through the construction.

`UserDataService` has a chain of dependencies: `UserDataService -> UserRepository -> Context`. So it would be good to use Ninject here.

The problem is, when I uncomment `[Inject]` above `userData` declaration, and try getting Ninject to inject object as a parameter, it does not work for some reason: I get null reference exceptions.

(*could it be that `UserDataService` does not have an interface and I'm binding the object to itself: `kernel.Bind<UserDataService>().ToSelf();` ??*)

I have another commented line in the code:

```
userDataService = DependencyResolver.Current
    .GetService<UserDataService>();
```

When this is uncommented, the set up works, I get correct objects inserted, but now we depend on DependencyResolver and that is not much better than saying `userDataService = new UserDataService()`

Am I missing something? Is there another way to inject an object as a parameter and not introducing dependency on Ninject or DependencyResolver?

Comment: Infection you say?

Comment: @JLevett: depending on how you inject those dependencies, they might get infected :-)

Comment: +1 just for the "good laugh typo of the day" :-)

Comment: @JLevett that was not a typo, deliberate. From this article: http://www.beefycode.com/post/Dependency-Infection.aspx

Comment: @trailmax: How funny the 'Dependency infection' title might be, it doesn't help with the queryability of this subject on google. Questions on Stackoverflow are for the community, so please let your question be useful for the community and fix this 'typo' in the title.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A model binder should just do data conversion and should not depend on any services and certainly not trigger any database communication. That should be done in another part of your application. Your Action method should just take a `Guid userId` and you should call `userDataService.GetUser(UserID);` from within your controllers (or in a lower layer, for instance, inside a [business command](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91)). By doing this, your problem will not exist.

Comment: Yeah, I had that in the first place, but then I had userData.GetUser(UserID) all over controllers, in every call. Also controllers were confused with two Guid objects being passed in: Delete(Guid ID, Guid UserID) and instead of object ID, controller was given two UserID. Unless there is a way to solve this problem...

Comment: @trailmax: Then there is probably something wrong with your routing. And if not, move create a new question here at SO. Nontheless, you are fixing this problem in the wrong way.

Comment: Model binders create type instances and the sub-type created might depend on the type of the item you're binding. So if you only have a key then you need to look up the type which might be in a database!

Answer (score 5):

You could do this:

```
public class UserModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Func<UserDataService> UserData { get; set; }

    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        Guid UserID = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;

        User u = UserData().GetUser(UserID);

        return u;
    }
}
```

Then when you wire it up:

```
ModelBinders.Binders[typeof(User)] = new UserModelBinder() 
{  
    userData = () => DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<UserDataService>();
}
```

The benefit is that your `UserModelBinder` isn't aware that a container is being used, while still being open for injection.

But I agree with [Steven](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10850824/57132) - using a model binder for this doesn't seem quite right. Instead you might inject an `ICurrentUserContext` into your controllers, where the implementation returns the current user. Then you don't even need to add a parameter to your controller actions.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `DependencyResolver.Current` to get your service.  This is actually *much* better than using `new`, because it means you have not coupled getting that service to the type of the service.  You can decide later to make `UserDataService` an abstraction and plug in different variants without changing your client code, which is really the whole point.

Also, `DependencyResolver.Current` is a settable `IDependencyResolver`, so you could implement that interface yourself, with a class that backs it with Ninject if you like that framework.

Another way to do dependency injection in MVC3 is to setup your own `IControllerActivator`, which allows you to do constructor injection instead, if you like.

Comment: Yeah, I understand what DependencyResolver does and why it is better than creating via "new". Should any class be ignorant of DI going on at all? Hence the title "infection".

Comment: You mean should most of your classes be ignorant of your DI framework?  Absolutely, almost all of them should be ignorant of it! It should be encapsulated too.  See this great article from Uncle Bob on the topic: http://blog.objectmentor.com/articles/2010/01/17/dependency-injection-inversion