# Can ninject resolve dependency when posting data with ajax?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, ninject

I am using `System.Web.Mvc.Ajax` to do form post. The model its trying to post contains a property of type `ISomeInterface`. When posting the form data, I get the exception `MissingMethodException: Cannot create an instance of an interface. Object type 'Model.Abstract.ISomeInterface'.`

All related ninject bindings are done correctly. If I change the property type to its concrete implementation, the model binds successfully. Am I doing something wrong here?

This is the form

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("_AddNote", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post" }))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Note.NoteBody)
    <input type="submit" value="Post"/>
}
```

This is where the form is posted

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult _AddNote(StudentViewModel postedData)
{
    //add note stuff;
}
```

This is the model modelbinder is trying to bind to

```
public class StudentViewModel
{
    public INote Note { get; set;}
    //Other Properties
}
```

Comment: You need to show code for your action and custom model binder/registration so this question can be answered... (Also check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848560/using-dependency-injection-in-asp-net-mvc3-model-binder for guidance on when to avoid DI in model binder).

Comment: You cant bind to an interface. The `DefaultModelBinder` needs in initialize an instance of your model in order to set the properties (how would it know what instance to create!). Suggest you read [The Features and Foibles of ASP.NET MVC Model Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx)